# send image from server to client in socket io

Tags: reactjs, image, socket.io

recently i was practiced socket io chat app and i was trying to send image but i don't know how to do so...is there anyone who can help me out in implementing image sending method in socket io.

server code

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("message", ({ name, message }) => {
    io.emit("message", { name, message });
  });
  
});

server.listen(4000, function () {
  console.log("listening on port 4000");
});
```

client code

```
 return (
    <>
      <h1>Chat With Your Doctor Now</h1>
      <div className="box">
        <form onSubmit={onMessageSubmit}>
          <h1>Message Section</h1>
          <div>
            <input
              name="message"
              onChange={(e) => onTextChange(e)}
              value={state.message}
              id="outlined-multiline-static"
              variant="outlined"
              label="Message"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="file" accept="image"/>
          </div>
          <button>Send Message</button>
        </form>
        <div className="render-chat">
          <h1>Conversation</h1>
          {renderChat()}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

i'm trying to get help and expecting some help

Comment: I don't use socket.io, But I think you need an HTML page to upload the image, then read it `FileReader` and you can use `readAsDataURL ` and send it to the other client ( I don't think you can read the image without input of type file ).

Comment: you see i've an input sector for image but i don't know to how to implement it

Comment: You do have for the client, so make other client,
- client_1 ---> selecting the image, use FileReader and readAsDataURL.
- Server ---> Receiving from client_1 and send it to client_2.
- open a new tab as client_2 --> Receving the image from server.

Comment: can you give me sample code for this ??